# Two threads running the same io_service

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

https://youtu.be/rwOv_tw2eA4?t=1030

This example has one io_service and two threads running on it.

- the io_service has two tasks attached to it: timer1 and timer2
- two threads are created to run the io_service

```
void timer_expired( std:: string id )
{
    std::cout << timestamp() << ": " << id << ": begin\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(3) );
    std::cout << timestamp() << ": " << id << ": end\n";
}

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer1( io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(5) );
    boost::asio::deadline_timer timer2( io_service, boost::posix_time::seconds(5) );

    timer1.async_wait( []( auto ... ){ timer_expired("timer1"); });
    timer2.async_wait( []( auto ... ){ timer_expired("timer2"); });


    std::cout << timestamp() << ": calling io_service run\n";

    std::thread thread1( [&](){ io_service.run(); } );
    std::thread thread2( [&](){ io_service.run(); } );

    thread1.join();
    thread2.join();

    std::cout << timestamp() << ": done\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Every time I run this sample the output looks ok, in that:

- the two timers started at the same time
- the two timers expired at the same time (after 5s, they were async)
- the callbacks were invoked at the same time (after 3s)

The author stated that this code has race in there andshould not work (garage output).

What's not very clear is that we have two threads, each can serve one completion handler (here the timer callback). So why race? And the fact that I ran this code several times and unable to produce any garbage output as what the author presented.

The output looks as expected, here's a sample:

```
2019-07-28 11:27:44: calling io_service run
2019-07-28 11:27:49: timer1: begin
2019-07-28 11:27:49: timer2: begin
2019-07-28 11:27:52: timer1: end
2019-07-28 11:27:52: timer2: end
2019-07-28 11:27:52: done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handlers are invoked within `io_service::run`. You started two threads where `io.run()` works. So you have two runnig methods `timer_expired` at the same time. And the race is while accessing `cout` stream.

You are just lucky to see this nice output, but when you add some more works in `timer_expired`:

```
void timer_expired( std:: string id )
{
    std::cout << timestamp() << ": " << id << ": begin\n";
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::seconds(3) );
    // ADD MORE LINES TO BE PRINTED
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        std::cout << timestamp() << ": " << id << ": end" << std::endl;
}
```

you will see interleaved characters.

Accessing by many threads `cout` object doesn't lead to crash (according to [reference](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/iostream.objects#overview)),

> Concurrent access to a synchronized ([ios.members.static]) standard
>   iostream object's formatted and unformatted input and output functions
>   or a standard C stream by multiple threads shall not result in a data
>   race. [ Note: Users must still synchronize concurrent use of these
>   objects and streams by multiple threads if they wish to avoid
>   interleaved characters.

but to avoid these interleaved chars you have to add synchronization when accessing `cout` for example by using `std::mutex`, or call handlers in serially manner - use [`strand`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_context__strand.html) object from boost.

Comment: It's probably not that I'm lucky, but that my PC is too fast ;) For my setup, it takes `i` at least 200 to see any interleaved characters, ie when race happens.

Comment: I can see on the following slides he mentioned `strand`. As `strand` serialises the access to the completion handler, it probably doesn't make any sense to have 2 threads (as no two threads can access `timer_expired` simultaneously).

Comment: Yes you are right, in this particular case using `strand` is overkill, to protect printing lines mutex is sufficient.

Comment: @rafix07 Why overkill ? ASIO is offering strand features, less code than using a mutex, more scalable, you stay in the ASIO ecosystem... IMHO you have to use a strand.